# Jenkins JNLP slave fails to build, shows no log

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, jnlp, jenkins

when running a Jenkins slave via JNLP on a Windows machine, the build start fine and clones the git repository. However, the log ends up like this:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building remotely on xxx
Checkout:Project / c:\jenkins-slave\workspace\Project - hudson.remoting.Channel@12dd731:EC2
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision e62b587a61fe6d4966fb2e014480a3b1bf638e97 (origin/master)
Checkout:Project / c:\jenkins-slave\workspace\Project - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1ab307c
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:xxx
Commencing build of Revision e62b587a61fe6d4966fb2e014480a3b1bf638e97 (origin/master)
Checking out Revision e62b587a61fe6d4966fb2e014480a3b1bf638e97 (origin/master)
FATAL: ERROR
Finished: FAILURE
```

So, the Jenkins build fails but there is no error log. I can't find one on the master or slave. Anyone have any ideas or a pointer to the log file?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: For the logging: have you checked via the console? "Manage Jenkins" -> "System Log" for the master or "slave name" -> Log for the slave?

Comment: Found the problem -- the Jenkins project was referring to a version of Gradle that was present in the master, but not on the remote node. So Jenkins could not find the gradle executable to run.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem -- the Jenkins project was referring to a version of Gradle that was present in the master, but not on the remote node. So Jenkins could not find the gradle executable to run.